# rspec writes log to stdout instead of test.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have clear application. I set up rspec and capybara. And I write simple test.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Log in", type: :feature do
  scenario 'as user' do
    User.create!(email: 'user@eample.com', password: 'password')
    visit '/users/sign_in'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'user@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    click_on 'Log in'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Signed in successfully.'
  end
end
```

This test push server's log to stdout(or stderr). So test input looks like this

```
> rspec
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
User Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "user@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$6iqFDQXgBy/bC/1lYdzLV...1Da18lRiTyDaMJpWdi7EiK68Dcm6."], ["created_at", "2015-12-01 17:09:33.264145"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-01 17:09:33.264145"]]

...

Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 18.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
.

Finished in 0.49195 seconds (files took 0.45766 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
...
rspec (3.4.0)
...
capybara (2.5.0)
...
```

`spec_helper.rb` and `rails-helper.rb` are default.

I tried to add example which do not use capybara:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Array do
  it { should respond_to :count }
end
```

but it returns similar output

```
> rspec spec/models/fake_test_spec.rb
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
.

Finished in 0.00257 seconds (files took 0.36298 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

What is wrong? I have never see same behaviour yet. It is just out of the box. I don't change `stderr` or `stdout` variables...

Answer (score 1):

Oh no... I confuse readers... I set up my app for deploy to heroku and use `gem 'rails_12factor'`. It changes logger behaviour. So I move this gem to `production` group and all work fine.